# How do I block requests to Apache on a network interface?

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx

The problem: I have a local Apache instance on my Macbook Pro. I need it to listen on all network interfaces except en0 and en1 (basically, listen on lo and vnicX from Parallels).

I know about "Listen *:80" but this is not a solution in this particular case. The only thing I could imagine if to use OS X firewall to block incoming requests to Apache on those interfaces. But I could not find any working examples and could not make such rules myself.

Could somebody help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache can be [configured](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html) to listen either on all addresses (`Listen *:80`), or on particular addresses (`Listen 192.168.23.42:80`). It can't be configured to *not* listen on particular addresses (or interfaces for that matter). If you want that, you have use a [firewall](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/ipfw.8.html) to block connections on those interfaces. Something like this might do the trick:

```
ipfw add deny any to dst-port 80 in via en0
ipfw add deny any to dst-port 80 in via en1
```

Comment: As I wrote in the question, I am looking for firewall rules...

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Just note Mac OSX lion and above use pf not ipfw

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with using the Firewall settings instead. They're in Settings -> Security & Privacy -> Firewall.

Comment: It does not let to block certain interfaces. It is all or nothing.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the OS X security guide, I used ipfw. It works ok in Mountain Lion. Here is what I did:

Create a file named /etc/ipfw.conf with the following content:

```
 add 1000 deny tcp from any to any dst-port 80 via en0
 add 2000 deny tcp from any to any dst-port 80 via en1
```

You may want to go for slightly different set of rules (like block all but allow "lo0" interface) if you use a USB modem.

Create a file named /Library/LaunchDaemons/ipfw.plist with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://
     www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
    <string>ipfw</string>
  <key>Program</key>
    <string>/sbin/ipfw</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/sbin/ipfw</string>
      <string>/etc/ipfw.conf</string>
    </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true />
</dict>
</plist>
```

Register with launchd:

```
 launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/ipfw.plist
```

Check that rules are registered:

```
ipfw print
```

You should get:

```
01000 deny tcp from any to any dst-port 80 via en0
02000 deny tcp from any to any dst-port 80 via en1
65535 allow ip from any to any
```

The last rule *is* needed!

Now you can try to connect from *another computer* to your own and check that connection is blocked. Note that you are always able to connect from your own computer to your own computer. Try your smartphone or friend's computer.